# Exponential distribution of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Random variable $X$ has probability density function $g(x)=\frac{3}{7}x^2\mathbf{1}_{[1,2]}$. Is there a function $F: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which $F(X)$ has an exponential distribution with parameter 1? Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange.  Since this is a learning community, we expect you to post some information about what you've tried or thought about and, as precisely as possible, what your difficulty is.  Please consider making an edit to include this information so our help can be more targeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $F$ does exist, because you only have to redistribute the values going to $[1,2]$ to values going to $(0,\infty)$. But how to find $F$ explicitely? It must satisfy $F(1)=0$, $F(2)=\infty$ (so strictly speaking the function **will not** be $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, or at least not continuously). What we need is

$\int_1^x g(t)dt=\int_0^{F(x)}e^{-t}dt=1-e^{-F(x)}$, and you may calculate $F$ (just calculate the first integral as a function of $x$ and rearrange).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it and solution is $F(t)=\ln(\frac{7}{8-x^3})$ for $x\in [1,2)$. Can I just define $F(x)=0, x\not\in [1,2)$?

Comment: @user231964 Of course (but the function will not be continuous)

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding cdf is:

$$G_X(x)=\begin{cases}0, & \text{ if }x<1\\
\frac{1}{7}x^3& \text{ if }1\le x<2\\
 0, & \text{ otherwise. }\end{cases}.$$
 Let us calculate the distribution of the random variable $G(X)$. Let it be denoted by $H$:
$$H(x)=P(G_X(X)<x)=P(X<G_X^{-1}(x))=G_X(G_X^{-1}(x))=x$$
over the interval $[1,2]$. That is, the distribution of $Y=G_X(X)-1$ is uniform over $[0,1]$.

Now, the question is the following: Can one generate an exponential distribution if a random variable of uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ is given?

I hope that you already know the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't cdf $G_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}0,   if x<1\\ \frac{1}{7}(x^{3}-1),  if 1\le x<2\\1     otherwise\end{cases}$ ?